# Xcode - SwiftUI Preview Inside SPM Package Error "Could not find host for previews"

Tags: xcode, swiftui, swift-package-manager, swiftui-previews

I am using a SPM package and added one simple `DashboardView` inside the package as below:

```
import SwiftUI

struct DashboardView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello World")
    }
}

struct DashboardView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        DashboardView()
    }
}
```

When I try to preview `DashboardView`, I get error:

`Cannot preview in this file`

`Could not find host for previews`

[image: Preview Error Detail]

Tried on Xcode 13.4.1, 14.0.1, 14.1_beta_3 but error is same.

Comment: I had this when the Widget file's target membership was both the main app as well as the WidgetExtension. Unchecking the main target fixed it in that case.

Answer (score 2):

In Package.swift file of my SPM Package, I just removed the line below which defines library type as static and error is gone.

```
let package = Package(
...

products: [
    // Products define the executables and libraries a package produces, and make them visible to other packages.
    .library(
        name: "MyKit",
        type: .static, // <- This line removed
        targets: ["MyKit"]
    ),
]

...
```